# php: different between array( ) and { }

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

what's the different between

```
Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [username] => user
        [first_name] => hello
        [last_name] => world
    )
```

and

```
{
    user_id: "1",
    username:"user",
    first_name:"hello",
    last_name:"world"
}
```

? and how to convert them in php?

Edit: add details

Actually i'm using redis zunionstore and zrevrange to combine user data. The result returns me something like :

```
Array
(
    [0] =>{"user_id":"1","username":"user","first_name:hello","last_name:world"}
    [1] => ...
)
```

Since i have to process the data, i want something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [username] => user
            [first_name] => hello
            [last_name] => world
        )
 ...
)
```

So is there any easy way to convert it instead of using for loop to json_decode each element?
Thx

Comment: one is an array, the other is json

Comment: Convert them to what?

Comment: ask your real question - without context, this is meaningless

Comment: @John: That is not even JSON.

Comment: @john: nope. "other one" is javascript. json would have quoted keys.

Comment: After your edit: Indeed, the array seems to contain JSON strings and iterating over each element is the only way to decode them. You *could* use `array_map` but it does not add any advantages in this case.

Comment: just a tip: using `var_dump` instead of `print_r` normally more precisely shows the values. that can be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4):

The first string is the output of the `print_r` function. Example:

```
$array=array('key'=>'value');
print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [key] => value
)
```

Your second is JSON-like, alto it lacks of double-quotes for keys.
You **can't** convert them directly.

You could convert JSON to a PHP array with `json_decode` if your second string was something like this:

```
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "username":"user"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one, as stated is PHP and second one is a JavaScript array.

To convert array to JSON, use `json_encode()`;

---

To convert JavaScript array to JSON text and later to PHP array(associative); use `JSON.stringify()` and `json_decode()`.

---

For your task, the best bet would be `array_walk` function:

```
array_walk( "json_decode", $MyArry );
```

Comment: No, it's not JSON. Keys must be strings in JSON.

Comment: The keys need to be quoted with `"` to be json.

Comment: The first one is not PHP. It's the output of `print_r`. It will not parse in PHP...

Comment: @FelixKling Updated with a solution ^_^ Thanks

Comment: uhm :) It's not a JavaScript array either... it's... I don't know what it is.

Comment: @FelixKling http://eval.in/14982

Comment: It's a JavaScript **object**. An array is a particular kind of object, and due to JS being rather awful in this regard, you can abuse it as a general-purpose object, but the thing in the question is *not* an array.