# Wordpress - array not treated as array if manually entered

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress site to track user progress. I have created a custom user text field called `completed_sections` which stores an array of sections of my website the user has completed. I am building that array like this:

```
<?php
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    global $completed;
    $completed = get_field('completed_sections', 'user_'.$userID);
  }

  function update_completed_sections() {
    global $completed;
    global $userID;
    $completedID = $_POST['quizID'];
    $completionDate = $_POST['date'];
    $completed_section[] = array(
      'ID' => $completedID,
      'date' => $completionDate
    );
    if (!empty($completed)) {
      $combined = array_merge($completed, $completed_section);
    } else {
      $combined = $completed;
    }
    update_field('completed_sections', $combined, 'user_'.$userID);
  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_complete_section', 'update_completed_sections');
?>
```

This is working perfectly fine so long as I am using an AJAX call to fire the `update_completed_sections` function. The array that is added to the custom user field looks like this:

```
[{"ID":"58","date":"07\/31\/20"},{"ID":"79","date":"08\/03\/20"}]
```

However, if I go in to the user section of the Wordpress backend and manually try tp update the array, it breaks it. Even if I don't change anything and I just go in there and hit "Update User" it will cause Wordpress not to treat that field as an array anymore. Any ideas on how to make sure this field is treated as an array, even if it is manually entered through the `Users` section of Wordpress or through PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: FYI, that is not an array - see this question [php: different between array( ) and { }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841484/php-different-between-array-and)

Comment: @FluffyKitten why is it treated as an array if it's built with the  AJAX call, but not if it's manually updated through the backend?

Comment: @FluffyKitten also, if I use the `is_array()` conditional on the `$completed` variable, it returns true, even after updating it through the backend.